# java- how to return multiple columns in JPA for email?

Tags: java, jpa

I wrote a program where I let my program endlessly pick up records from my `emailqueue` table so that it can process the records and send the email to outsiders.First the code is like below:

```
 MySqlConnect con=new MySqlConnect();
    public PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    public Connection con1 = con.connect();



    //pick up queue and send email
    public void email() throws Exception {


        try{

            while(true) {
                String sql = "SELECT id,user,subject,recipient,content FROM emailqueue WHERE status='Pending' ";
                PreparedStatement statement = con1.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();



                while (rs.next()) {

                    String subject = rs.getString("subject");

                    String recipient = rs.getString("recipient");

                    String content = rs.getString("content");

                    String id = rs.getString("id");
                    String username = rs.getString("user");

                    String emailStatus = "DONE";
                    String errormsg=sendEmail(recipient, subject, content, id,username);
                    if (!errormsg.equals("")) {
                        emailStatus = "FAILED";

                    }
                    TerminalLogger.printMsg("Status  : " + emailStatus);

                }
                statement.close();
                rs.close();

            }
```

As you can see,I used JDBC driver to get the value of each column in the table and passed them to `sendEmail` where it does it's work to send email.Sure,so far everything works flawlessly.

Now,I want to achieve the same goal by using JPA because I want to learn more about it and i'm new to it.So I added a database mapping to my email table,like below:

Emailqueue.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emailqueue")

public class Emailqueue {
    private long ulnodeid;
    private String user;
    private String subject;
    private String recipient;
    private String content;
    private String status;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public long getUlnodeid() {
        return ulnodeid;
    }

    public void setUlnodeid(long ulnodeid) {
        this.ulnodeid = ulnodeid;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "USER")
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "SUBJECT")
    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "RECIPIENT")
    public String getRecipient() {
        return recipient;
    }

    public void setRecipient(String recipient) {
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CONTENT")
    public String  getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }







    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Emailqueue that = (Emailqueue) o;
        return ulnodeid == that.ulnodeid &&
                user == that.user &&
                Objects.equals(subject, that.subject) &&
                Objects.equals(recipient, that.recipient) &&
                Objects.equals(content, that.content) &&
                Objects.equals(status, that.status);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(ulnodeid, user,subject,recipient,content,status);
    }
}
```

I wrote a method to retrieve records from the table using Entity Manager,below:

```
public Emailqueue getrecords() {
        try {

            String sql = "select object(o) from Emailqueue as o where " +
                    "status='" + "Pending" + "'";

            List resList = em.createQuery(sql).getResultList();
            if (resList == null) {
                throw new Exception("Error with selection query.");
            }

            if (resList.size() > 0) {
                return (Emailqueue) resList.get(0);
            }

           // msg = "Setting <" + name + "> not found.";

            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            msg = CoreUtil.wrapMsg(CoreUtil.FUNC_ERROR,
                    this.getClass().getName(), "get(" + "Pending" + ")", e.getMessage());


            return null;
        }
    }
```

I mainly need `recipient,subject,content,id and username` records so i could pass it to the method. How would I retrieve values for each row where the status is pending in this case using JPA?

Edit:

Using a for loop:

```
public void email() throws Exception {


        try{

            while(true) {

                String sql = "select p.id,p.user,p.subject,p.recipient,p.content from Emailqueue p where " +
                        "status='Pending'";
                List<Emailqueue> emailList = em.createQuery(sql).getResultList();
                for (Emailqueue obj : emailList) {
                    String emailStatus = "DONE";
                    String errormsg=sendEmail(obj.getRecipient(), obj.getSubject(), obj.getContent(),obj.getUlnodeid(),obj.getUser());
                    if (!errormsg.equals("")) {
                        emailStatus = "FAILED";
                    }
                    TerminalLogger.printMsg("Status  : " + emailStatus);
                }

            }
```

Comment: try replacing your `getrecord` method with some `spring` method - see https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Is there other alternatives without spring,like without jdbc as well and able to obtain result set in other ways.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the query call with:

```java
List<Emailqueue> res = em.createQuery("SELECT e from Emailqueue e WHERE e.status='Pending'",
                                          Emailqueue.class).getResultList();
```

This will return a list of matching instances as Java objects (entities), which you can easily work with by calling getters/setters, for example (using the `sendEmail` method from your question):

```java
for (Emailqueue eq : res) {
   sendStatus = sendEmail(eq.getRecipient(), eq.getSubject(), eq.getContent(), eq.getId(), eq.getUsername());
}
```

Or, better yet, change the signature of `sendEmail` to `sendEmail(Emailqueue eq)` and call the getters in the method.

Comment: I did that,but how do i pass the param to sendmessage?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Your solution works but how do i ensure it keeps running as long as there is new record inserted to emailqueue table?

Comment: Well, if there are new records inserted into the table, you need to run the routine repeatedly. If this insertion happens inside your application, you can use application-wide notifications. If it happens externally, I suppose polling at regular intervals can do the job. You can take a look for example at [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: At this moment,I'm just using while(true) loop to keep it running but i fear it could be taxing to the CPU when the table has no records so I added Thread.Sleep to minimize the tax.